# Adding Spring Boot Data JPA dependency causes Spring Boot project to crash on launch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

When I simply add the Spring Boot JPA dependency to a basic Spring Boot Starter Project and then try to run the project through Boot Dashboard, it immediately crashes with an IllegalStateException. There is no problem if I remove the dependency again. I will post the stack trace below. What can I do to fix this?

The dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar file:/C:/Users/stan_/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.3.7.Final/hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.fromClassLoader(ChangeableUrls.java:98)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:92)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getInitialUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.<init>(Restarter.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:556)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:50)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.stanostr.springjdbc.SpringAuthenticationWithJdbcApplication.main(SpringAuthenticationWithJdbcApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromManifestClassPathAttribute(ChangeableUrls.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:129)
    ...
```

Comment: Remove the artifact from your local repository and rebuild your app

Comment: Try deleting the hibernate jars from .m2\repository and update the snapshot from ide.

Comment: You have a corrupt hibernate jar. Just delete it from m2 folder like its `C:\Users\stan_.m2\repository\org\hibernate`. Delete all the files in hibernate and download it again through maven

Comment: Thank you, I was able to resolve it by simply going to the specified directory and deleting the file and then downloading it again through maven. Maybe there were other ways of doing this too. I don't know, should I delete this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the `Class-Path` of your `hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar` is correct and make sure that the `jar` actually exist in the indicated repository. If the `jar` is present, you can manually add it in your project through Build path/library/add external jars.

Comment: Yes, it was present. I deleted it and then redownloaded it and I was able to make it work. Thank you.